# Primary key ambiguities in foreign key statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints

Does Oracle automatically determine primary keys in constraint statements?

Such as

```
CREATE TABLE [BANK] (
   [bank_id] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (bank_id)
);

CREATE TABLE [ACCOUNT] (
   [account_id] SMALLINT NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (account_id)
);


CONSTRAINT fk_bank_id FOREIGN KEY (bank_id)
   REFERENCES BANK /* put this in account create table statement */
```

would it automatically determine the BANK table's primary key when I don't explicitly state the primary key and instead just use the table name?

Does the naming convention of (abstraction):

```
PRIMARY KEY (primary_key)
```

affect constraint clause and if so, in what ways?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for the references clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52187) shows the referenced column name as optional. So we can create a foreign key specifying only the referenced table....

```
SQL> create table t23 (
  2  id number not null
  3  , col_1 varchar2(10) not null
  4  , constraint t23_pk primary key (id)
  5  )
  6  /

Table created.

SQL> create table t42 (
  2  id number not null
  3  , fk_id number not null
  4  , col_a varchar2(10)
  5  , col_b varchar2(10)
  6  , constraint t23_pk primary key (id)
  7  , constraint t42_t23_fk foreign key (fk_id) references t23
  8  )
  9  /

Table created.

SQL>
```

Easy peasy lemon squeezy.  Let's up the stakes by adding a unique key to the parent table....

```
SQL> drop table t23 cascade constraints;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table t42 cascade constraints;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t23 (
  2  id number not null
  3  , col_1 varchar2(10) not null
  4  , constraint t23_pk primary key (id)
  5  , constraint t23_uk unique (col_1)
  6  )
  7  /
Table created.

SQL> create table t42 (
  2  id number not null
  3  , fk_id number not null
  4  , col_a varchar2(10)
  5  , col_b varchar2(10)
  6  , constraint t42_pk primary key (id)
  7  , constraint t42_t23_fk foreign key (fk_id) references t23 
  8  )
  9  /

Table created.

SQL>
```

Oracle still figures out the primary key.  But suppose we want to reference that unique key instead?

```
SQL> drop table t42 cascade constraints;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t42 (
  2  id number not null
  3  , fk_id number not null
  4  , col_a varchar2(10)
  5  , col_b varchar2(10)
  6  , constraint t42_pk primary key (id)
  7  , constraint t42_t23_fk foreign key (col_a) references t23 
  8  )
  9  /

     , constraint t42_t23_fk foreign key (col_a) references t23
                                         *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type


SQL> create table t42 (
  2  id number not null
  3  , fk_id number not null
  4  , col_a varchar2(10)
  5  , col_b varchar2(10)
  6  , constraint t42_pk primary key (id)
  7  , constraint t42_t23_fk foreign key (col_a) references t23 (col_1)
  8  )
  9  /

Table created.

SQL>
```

So we can see, [as the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52199), Oracle defaults the referenced key to be the primary key. When we want to reference another key we have to identify the constrained columns in the referenced table.

> "Does the naming convention of (abstraction):"

Not sure where you got that "convention" from.  It's not supported by the syntax so its effect is to hurl an exception, `ORA-00904: "PRIMARY_KEY": invalid identifier` (or `ORA-00907` if you try without the underscore ).  This makes sense because the primary key is the referenced default, and it couldn't work for referencing a unique key because tables can have more than one of those.

Answer (score 0):

'not sure this is what you are looking for. But to quote [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2903):

> **Foreign Key Constraints**
>   [...]
>    If you identify only the parent table or view and omit the column name, then the foreign key automatically references the primary key of the parent table or view. The corresponding column or columns of the foreign key and the referenced key must match in order and datatype.